# What species are these, beetle eggs?

Tags: species-identification

I posted a thread the other day and identified I have carpet beetles larvae. I have a pest control company booked to treat the place on Monday but in the meantime I’ve found these little things on the wall that keep appears and I’m wondering if these are the eggs stage of the beetles or perhaps an entirety different species? Someone on a Facebook group suggest they could just be wax or food, but how would either randomly just appear on the walls?

Size wise they are about half the size of a grain of rice or perhaps a little bigger.

Just been googling, could it be instar stage of bed bugs?

I’m based in London, UK.

enter image description here
[image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YpEiI.jpg)

[image]
[image]

Comment: food (or snot-stuff) can appear to 'randomly' appear (i.e. appear unexpectantly) on walls or ceiling simply from a cough or a sneeze

Answer (score 2):

These are not instars or eggs. These are debris from food or perhaps ear wax or something similar.

If they were instars you would see either a uniform larval shape - usually [bilaterally symmetrical](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/glossary/bilateral-symmetry/), or you would see something that indicated a body form like legs, head etc. You would also expect that they would be about the same size and shape in each case, though different age/stage larvae can have different sizes.

If they were eggs, you would generally expect them to be both the same size and both the same shape if they came from the same species. They would also be very large eggs for common insects; most butterfly eggs for example are in the 1-2 mm range, rather than 5-7 mm.